# Not printing first element of array to decimal precision in C++

Tags: c++

I'm taking input for "cost" and "quantity" and printing total as "cost*quantity" after giving a discount of 10% for quantity>1000 and achieving this using array.

However, when I', trying to print output the first line of output is not giving precise decimal values.

Problem statement: https://www.codechef.com/problems/FLOW009/

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

    int n;
    int comp = 0;
    std::cout.precision(6);

    std::cin >> n;

    float cost[n];
    float qty[n];
    float total[n];

    for (int i=0; i<n; i++){
        std::cin>>cost[i]>>qty[i];
    }

    while (comp < n){
        if(cost[comp]>1000){
            cost[comp] = cost[comp] - cost[comp]*0.10;
        }
        comp++;
    }

    for(int z=0; z<n; z++){
        total[z] = cost[z]*qty[z];
    }

    for (int j=0; j<n; j++){
        std::cout<< total[j] << std::fixed << std::endl;
    }

}
```

I've used `std::cout.precision()` and `std::fixed` properly

Input:

```
3 
100 120
10 20
1200 20
```

Expected output:

```
12000.000000
200.000000
21600.000000
```

Actual output:

```
12000
200.000000
21600.000000
```

Comment: Please edit your code into the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're outputting the first value ***before*** you've sent `std::fixed` to `std::cout` (on the first run through the output loop)! Try this simple correction:

```
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
//  std::cout<< total[j] << std::fixed << std::endl; // total[0] goes out BEFORE std::fixed!
    std::cout << std::fixed << total[j] << std::endl; // Send std::fixed BEFORE the number!
}
```

Or, for a more efficient way, just send `std::fixed` once, before the loop:

```
std::cout << std::fixed;
for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    std::cout << total[j] << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That was a silly mistake. It works now :D